# R, how to force to throw an error/warning if index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling, indexing

The default behavior in R when the index exceeds the dimensions of a vector / matrix is to return NA. E.g.

```
> a  = as.matrix(1:10)
> a[11]
[1] NA
```

This is very inconvenient in many circumstances, since the code keeps running giving wrong results and without even giving a warning. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to alter this default behavior in a code, so that in these cases an error or a warning is thrown instead of returning NA when the index exceeds the dimensions of a vector/matrix ?

Comment: You can use `stop()` to stop executing things and force an error. I would love to see the context you wish to use this. If one would implement `stop()` in your example it would produce an error, but I have no idea whether it would stop any loops or similar executions you had planned to do.

Comment: I want to make R change behavior, at least within the execution of a certain code, so that any following case in which an index exceeding the dimensions of a matrix is used issues a stop() instead of returning NA or at least a warning().

Comment: I need something like a line to put at the beginning of a code, an option that is valid for all the subsequent lines.

Comment: Consider writing a function that loops your execution for x times (x being the number of elements in your matrix). If you want to loop executions indefinitely consider adding an `if` operator that forces `stop()` after the loop incidents exceed the number of variables in your matrix.

Comment: This is one of rare cases where a broader context will help us give advice on how to proceed more effectively. Can you give us an example of where the index runs off?

Comment: The point is that I need a very general solution, not to apply "locally" a loop with a stop. Practically I want R to have by default the same behavior as, e.g., matlab, when dealing with indices that exceed the dimensions, i.e. to give error. But I need this to happen ALWAYS, not only on a small piece of code, since this problem can arise in an extremely wide array of cases, practically anytime you work with matrices. Pardon my reticence in providing a specific example, but I don't need ad hoc solution for a specific calculation.

Comment: The context might be something as simple as the example of the question, a case in which I need to extract a part of a data vector for subsequent calculation. But this is such a frequent occurrence that I cannot insert a function or a piece of code every time. I need to change the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is for you to use two arguments (row and col) when indexing your matrix with `[`, which is the more "normal" thing to do with a matrix. That usage will trigger an error:

```
a[11, 1] <- NA
# Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 11, 1, value = NA) : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, assuming that your `a[11]` is part of a script or function, is to put in your own error check.   For example,

```
for (j in 1:20 ) {
   ifelse(j <= length(a), a[j], cat('index out of bounds') ) 
   }
```